# How to display a 16 bit RGB tif image in QLabel using openCV and pyqt5?

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm new to programming in python. Currently I'm working on a program, where I need to display a 16 bit RGB tif image in a QLabel using openCV and pyqt5. I tried all the possible QImage format options from the QImage documentation, nothing seems to be working. I'm looking for a solution to this problem or any other alternative solution would be really appreciated.
Thank you very much

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

path = "e:/python/Delta1.tif"

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

input_image = cv2.imread(path,-1)
height, width, channels = input_image.shape
bytesPerLine = channels * width
qImg = QtGui.QImage(input_image.data, input_image.shape[1], input_image.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB16).rgbSwapped() 
pixmap01 = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImg)
pixmap_image = QtGui.QPixmap(pixmap01)
label_imageDisplay = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label_imageDisplay.setPixmap(pixmap_image)
label_imageDisplay.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
label_imageDisplay.setScaledContents(True)
label_imageDisplay.setMinimumSize(1,1)
label_imageDisplay.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Doesn't `pixmap_image = QtGui.QPixmap(path)` work?

Comment: Yes, it does work, but i need to do some analysis and scaling operations using OpenCV. So i thought it would be better if i could display the image in QLabel without changing the originality of the resulting image read and processed using OpenCV.